# Script Error after upgrading to Vaadin Grid Pro

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow, vaadin12

I've been prototyping a small web app with the free vaadin grid component, and recently tried using the commercial trial grid pro. Upon updating my maven pom and updating my class references from grid -> gridpro, I am running into error screens with "Script Error", and walls of red text.

I am running:
Java 1.8.0.202
Vaadin 12.04
Grid Pro 1.0.0
Eclipse 2018.12

The installation instructions for grid pro on the vaadin website state that you dont have to specify a version in your pom file as long as you have the Vaadin bom dependency. My maven instance forced me to specify a version for gridpro, so I went with the latest.

One last note - I have not yet been prompted to activate the grid pro trial. I was expecting something obvious to trigger, but haven't seen anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid Pro is not included in Vaadin 12 bom. It has been introduced in Vaadin 13.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Any major pitfalls I should watch out for going from 12->13?

Comment: "Any major pitfalls I should watch out for going from 12->13", I do not expect anything major.